# Lotus Domino Calendar REST Service unicode

Tags: php, lotus-domino, lotus

I'm trying to add Calendar event with room reservation using REST API by sending JSON. Everything works perfect until I don't want to use room name with unicode letters like \u00F3. I was trying to set different encodings but it failed. Is there any way to make it working?

Comment: You need to show the code for what you've attempted, and explain what you mean by "it failed":

Answer (score 1):

The REST calendar API used to have a problem interpreting some Unicode characters.  This affected creating new events (POST) and updating existing events (PUT).  The problem is fixed in the latest version of the calendar API from the [extlib on OpenNTF](http://extlib.openntf.org/).  It is also fixed in 9.0.1 FP5 -- which should be available soon.

I suggest trying the extlib, if possible.  If the problem still occurs, you'll need to describe it better.  Just edit your original question as Richard requested.  Then we'll try to help.